# How to create multiple console windows in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, windows, console

I've just started using XCode for about a week. I'm wondering if there is a way to have multiple console windows in one project. For example, one window for input - another for output - one more for user interface. It does not have to be in one project. I just want to have different console windows in order for the user interface and the output to not getting mixed together. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to run console applications in multiple windows on *NIX and OSX systems. Imagine what would happened if you run console app in SSH and it tried to create new console window. This is not the case with Windows OS, where you can call AllocConsole to create another console (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
If you want to simulate multiple console windows in one application, you can create Cocoa application with multiple windows and text boxes inside each of them (and change the background color to black and font to Courier).